# c# конверт Memory<char> в Memory<byte>

Tags: c#, .net-core

Нужно получить `Memory<byte>` из `string` без создания промежуточных массивов.

Для Span все просто

```
 var text = "Hello";
 var charSpan = text.AsSpan();
 var bytesSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(charSpan);
```

Но для Memory только часть пути

```
 var text = "Hello";
 var charMemory = text.AsMemory();
 а дальше????
```

Comment: @tym32167 тут же потеря информации будет, да и условие "без создания промежуточных массивов" не выполнено

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, точно, я как всегда, по диагонали прочитал вопрос )

Comment: А разве memory гарантированно конечный? Це ж указатель на неизвестно что, надо будет всяко перебрать в массив. Может я путаю, но так помню.

Comment: Просветите для того кто в танке, а какой смысл в этих 2-ух новых типах и в каких кейзах они используются?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Документацию видели: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.2#spant-and-memory ? По сути, это унифицированный указатель, который может указывать на разные типы массивов: управляемый, неуправляемый или выделенный stackalloc (или на часть такого массива). Поэтому он позволяет создать метод, который будет принимать любой из таких массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Например так (требует разрешения unsafe-кода):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Buffers;

namespace CilBytecodeParserTest
{
    class Program
    {
        unsafe class StringMemoryManager<T> : MemoryManager<T>
        {
            MemoryHandle h;            
            int len;

            public StringMemoryManager(string s)
            {                
                h = s.AsMemory().Pin();               
                len = s.Length * 2;
            }

            public override Span<T> GetSpan()
            {                
                return new Span<T>(h.Pointer, len/Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
            }

            public override MemoryHandle Pin(int elementIndex = 0)
            {
                return h; //useless
            }

            public override void Unpin()
            {
                //useless
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if(disposing) h.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "Hello";  
            var mngr = new StringMemoryManager<byte>(text);
            Memory<byte> mem = mngr.Memory;
        }

    }
}
```

MemoryHandle позволяет получить указатель для любого Memory. MemoryManager создает Memory на основе любого Span, а Span можно создать из указателя. Получается универсальный конвертор всего во все. Недостаток в том, что строка будет закреплена в памяти на все время работы с нею. Если же вы спрашиваете, как сделать это **нормально** (без низкоуровневых хаков), то, видимо, никак. Не нашел такого API.

Comment: Может я вообще не то делаю. У меня NetworkStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte>) и я туда напрямую хочу скидывать строки параллельно с массивами и Memory<byte>. Но отстутствие api преобразования Memory меня смущает - может вообще нельзя так со строкой (хотя...Span же то же самое, а с ним можно)

Comment: @vitidev Можно создать на основе NetworkStream объект StreamWriter, у него есть метод WriteAsync(String). Но это, конечно, немного не то: он осуществляет преобразование в указанную кодировку, а не просто передает сырые данные строки как есть. Что касается Span, то он существует только как локальная переменная, поэтому с ним позволяется делать больше, чем с Memory, у которого нет такого ограничения. Но тот факт, что Memory<char> получить можно, а Memory<byte> - нет, выглядит действительно странно.

Comment: 1 Я не хочу преобразовывать в byte[] перед отправкой.Это и мемори трафик на ровном месте и ArrayPool мало поможет в проблеме, ведь очень много одновременных потребителей этого пула у меня. 2 Span собственно рабочий объект, а Memory это враппер для кучи, потому у него рабочих методов нет. 3 А нельзя получить Memory<byte> потому что [вот я спросил](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38052) и не очень понял ответ

Comment: И поскольку я не вижу других вариантов (ну разве что Unsafe.As и вызов интернал конструктора Memory у которого подпись "без валидаци"), то уточняющий вопрос - почему Unpin переопределн с пустым телом? Могу ли я сделать, если мне надо 100 раз этот Memory, то пусть 1000 раз я получу из этого StringMemoryManager, где каждый раз будет пинить и отпускать, а не пинить "один раз и надолго"?

Comment: @vitidev Unpin переопределен с пустым телом, потому что нам нужен активный MemoryHandle в течение всего времени жизни StringMemoryManager - именно из него мы берем Span'ы, и эти Span'ы не должны вдруг стать ведущими в никуда из-за деятельности GC. Поэтому мы "пиним" сразу в конструкторе, а "отпускаем" в Dispose. Т.е. хотите отпустить - просто вызовите Dispose. Можете добавить финализатор, чтобы отпускалось автоматически, даже если забыть вызвать Dispose. Еще можно переделать, чтобы пинилось при первом обращении к GetSpan(), а не в конструкторе. Но пинить-отпускать многократно не получится.

Comment: @vitidev А ответ разработчиков corefx я тоже пока не понял

Comment: " не должны вдруг стать ведущими в никуда из-за деятельности GC" - это выходит, что обычные Memory<T> тоже запинены? или как они избегают этой засады с GC?